# Positiveness of a continuous function on an interval

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Consider a continuous function $f:D\subset \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Let $I \subset D$ be an interval. $f$ has a property that for each pair $x_{1},~x_{2}\in I$ with $x_{2} \ge x_{1}$, if $f(x_{1}) > 0$, then $f(x_{2}) > 0$.

Suppose $\inf I \in D$ and $f(\inf I) > 0 $. Then, can we say that $f(x) > 0$ for all $x \in I$?

In case that $\inf I \in I$, obviously we can it is true. But I am confused when $I$ is an open interval.

Please help me figure out. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f(\inf I)>0$, by continuity there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\left|x-\inf I\right|<\delta$ means
$$\left|f(x)-f(\inf I)\right|<\epsilon=\frac{f(\inf I)}{2}\text{.}$$

Next, note that as an open interval, $\forall\delta>0$ sufficiently small, $\inf I+\delta\in I$.